# Android, gradle. When I run the app on API 23, I get the error converting bytecode to dex. But my app works fine on other API

Tags: android, gradle

I launch my app on API 19, 24,25, and it works fine. But on API 23 my app doesn't launch, it crashes in stage of building (gradle). 
Errors are:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes 
(the number of such errors is 28)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
Return code 1 for dex process
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

How to solve this problem?
Sorry for my poor knowledge of English.

Answer (score 0):

Compile this in Your build.gradle-:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't help (maybe I did wrong). When I wrote this in "dependencies", gradle sync crashed with "Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler". And when I replaced "implementation" with "compile", nothing changed.

Comment: Use *compile* instead of *implementation* on lower gradle versions. @DonnaLizard

Comment: I did so. But nothing changed.